# List contain only two last objects when I try add different objects

Tags: java, list, object, arraylist, genetic-algorithm

I create new chromosomes and add to list(I'm sure that chromosomes are different because I've printed them before adding) but in the end when I print list or get random index there are only two last chromosomes.(Generally during interation I create two new chromosomes from two random chromosomes from current generation in order to create new generation through crossover).

```
 public Population crossoverChromosomes(Population population, List<Item> items, int capacityOfKnapsack) {
        Random rand = new Random();
        List<Chromosome> chromosomeList = new ArrayList<>(population.getChromosomeList());

        int genesLength = population.chromosomeList.get(0).getGenes().length;
        int newGenes1[] = new int[genesLength];
        int newGenes2[] = new int[genesLength];

        ArrayList<Chromosome> newCrossoverPopulation = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int j = 0; j < population.getPopulationSize() / 2; j++) {

            int firstChrIndex = rand.nextInt(population.getPopulationSize() - 1);
            int secondChrIndex = rand.nextInt(population.getPopulationSize() - 1);
            int d = rand.nextInt(population.getPopulationSize() - 1);
            Chromosome firstChr = chromosomeList.get(firstChrIndex);
            Chromosome secondChr = chromosomeList.get(secondChrIndex);

            for (int i = 0; i < genesLength; i++) {
                if (i < d) {
                    newGenes1[i] = firstChr.getGenes()[i];
                    newGenes2[i] = secondChr.getGenes()[i];
                } else {
                    newGenes1[i] = secondChr.getGenes()[i];
                    newGenes2[i] = firstChr.getGenes()[i];
                }
            }
            Chromosome chr1 = new Chromosome(genesLength, newGenes1);
            Chromosome chr2 = new Chromosome(genesLength, newGenes2);
            chr1.fitnessCalculate(items, capacityOfKnapsack);
            newCrossoverPopulation.add(chr1);
            chr2.fitnessCalculate(items, capacityOfKnapsack);
            newCrossoverPopulation.add(chr2);

        }
        return new Population(newCrossoverPopulation.size(), newCrossoverPopulation);
    }
```

Comment: Did you try debugging?

Answer (score 0):

I've found problem, even if I use "new" operator during creating chromosomes, chr1 and chr2 and I add new chromosomes, finally every references refere only to chr1 or chr2 so to last two latest objects. Why it doesn't work? Maybe I should create new chromosomes this way list.add(new chr)? EDIT: it still doesn't work I have no idea why objects in list always refere to last two created chromosomes objects. 
EDIT2: SOLVED(I've created table only before loop and even if my objects was a new reference, variable "genes" in chromosome was still the same table that I've created before loop)